# The Second Moment of a Sum of Floor Functions

Tags: nt.number-theory

The following well known identity, where $\tau(n)$ denotes the number of divisors of $n$ appears in many number theory texts
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n \tau(k) = \sum_{d=1}^n \lfloor n/d \rfloor,
$$
and follows from the observation that "one out of d" integers in $\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$
are multiples of $d$ and then summing along rows $d$ as well as along columns $k$ the 
indicator function $1\{~ d~\mathrm{divides}~k~\}$.

Is there a good approximation, or are there any identities related to the following
sum, preferably containing arithmetic functions?
$$
 \sum_{d=1}^n \lfloor n/d \rfloor^2
$$

Comment: The sequence isn't in OEIS if I computed it correctly.

Comment: @joro Sometime after your comment, [A222548](https://oeis.org/A222548) has been added by Benoit Cloitre on Feb 24 2013

Answer (score 11):

Sums of this sort are well known to the experts - but since none of them have answered so far, let me try. Denoting the fractional part of a real $x$ by $\{x\}$, you can write your sum as
  $$ S = n^2 \sum_{d=1}^n \frac1{d^2} - 2n \sum_{d=1}^n \frac1d\left\{\frac nd\right\} + \sum_{d=1}^n \left\{\frac nd\right\}^2 = \frac{\pi^2}{6}\, n^2 + O(n\log n). $$

If you need more precision, you have to find the main term of the sum $\sum_d d^{-1}\{d^{-1}n\}$. The standard technique here, I believe, would be to use the Fourier expansion of the fractional part function, but you'd better contact experts for details, to avoid re-inventing the wheel.

---

Here is a different kind of answer, depending on what you are after. Your sum counts the number of triples $d,x,y\in[1,n]$ with $xd,yd\le n$. Since there are $\sum_{k=1}^n \tau(k)$ such triples with $x=y$, splitting the sum into two part according to whether $x\ge y$ or $y\ge x$, we can write it as 
  $$ S = 2 \sum_{dx\le n} x - \sum_{k=1}^n \tau(k). $$
Letting $k=dx$, we get
  $$ S = 2 \sum_{k=1}^n \sigma(k) - \sum_{k=1}^n \tau(k), $$
where $\sigma$ is the sum-of-divisors function. This gives you ``an identity containing arithmetic functions'', as you requested.

Comment: @Seva: Thank you that's very helpful, and I will look into the fourier expansion of the fractional part function

Comment: See my response for a supplement.

Answer (score 10):

This is a supplement to Seva's answer. The error term $O(n\log n)$ can be improved, but not considerably. $S$ is the summatory function of $2\sigma(k)-\tau(k)$ which exceeds $k\log\log k$ infinitely often, hence there is no continuous approximation to $S$ with an error less than $n\log\log n$. For $\sum_{k=1}^n\tau(k)$ the error can be improved to $(2\gamma-1)n+O(n^{7/22})$ or even better, but for $\sum_{k=1}^n\sigma(k)$ the best known error is $O(n(\log n)^{2/3})$, due to Walfisz (1963). See Chapter I.3 in Tenenbaum's Introduction to analytic and probabilistic number theory.

Comment: @GH: Thanks. How would the answers change if the upper limit of the sum was $v=v(n)$ for some positive, monotone function of $n$ satisfying $1< v(n) < n$? And what if the moment wasn't second but a higher moment? Perhaps $k=3,4$ and the sum was generalized to
$$
\sum_{d=1}^{v} \lfloor n/d \rfloor^k
$$
And where can I find information, if any, on the fourier expansion of the fractional part function?

Comment: @kodlu: Smaller terms do not necessarily yield a better error term. For example, the error term in the summatory function of the Mobius function is extremely tricky, closely connected to the Riemann Hypothesis. Regarding your second question: each moment is a different story. You see, my response only supplements Seva's which describes your sum in more arithmetic terms. The Fourier expansion of the fractional function is classical, see e.g. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions#Series_expansions Of course the coefficients don't decay fast as the function is not continuous.

Answer (score 5):

On your comment concerning the sum $\sum_{d\leq n}\left\lfloor\frac{n}{d}\right\rfloor^k$ for various natural numbers $k$, note we have:

$$\sum_{n\leq x}\left\lfloor\frac{x}{n}\right\rfloor^k=\sum_{n\leq x}\sum_{m\leq \frac{x}{n}}m^{k}-(m-1)^k=\sum_{n\leq x}\sum_{d\mid n}d^k-(d-1)^k$$

Thus since we can write: $$\sum_{d\mid n} d^k-(d-1)^k=\sum_{d\mid n}(d^k-\sum_{j=0}^k\binom{k}{j}d^{k-j}(-1)^j)=\sum_{d\mid n}\sum_{j=1}^k \binom{k}{j}d^{k-j}(-1)^{j-1}$$

This means if we let $\sigma_r(n)=\sum_{d\mid n}d^r$ then we must get for all $k\in \mathbb{N}$ that:
$$\sum_{n\leq x}\left\lfloor\frac{x}{n}\right\rfloor^k=\sum_{j=1}^k\binom{k}{j}(-1)^{j-1}\left(\sum_{n\leq x}\sigma_{k-j}(n)\right)$$